# Flutter: Failed to change device orientation on Ipad

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

Complete log:
Failed to change device orientation: Error Domain=UISceneErrorDomain Code=101 "The current windowing mode does not allow for programmatic changes to interface orientation." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The current windowing mode does not allow for programmatic changes to interface orientation.}

```
void _toggleFullScreen() async {
   
   await SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky);
    await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(const [
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    ]);
  }

  void _togglePortrait() async {
   
    await SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky);
    await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(const [
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
  }
```

I tried to programmatically change device orientation without success, is working on android and Iphone simulator but not on a real Ipad.

Comment: I got the same message now with CapacitorJS. Maybe this is intended by Apple? But what is even worse is that I cannot even lock the current orientation on iPad, which should definitely be possible, even when Apple might want to restrict changing it for UX reasons, which seems like a really bad idea too. Has anyone gotten this error on native IOS as well or is it a bridge-issue? Seems like I will have to work around this by prompting my users to change the orientation manually, whenever it's in the wrong orientation?

Answer (score 0):

#### iPad Orientation Lock

By default, an iPad allows Multitasking and its orientation cannot be locked. If you need to lock orientation on an iPad set the option Requires Full Screen to YES by adding the following to Info.plist:

```
<key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
<true/>
```

Taken from:
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/screen-orientation

Maybe it will help my flutter bruthers too :)